# Use JQuery to build an anchor

Tags: jquery, anchor

I want to use jquery to build HTML like this:

```
<li><a href="#"><span class="play"></span><span class="trackName">Track Name</span></a></li>
```

It seems simple but I can't figure it out how to include HTML tags as part of my anchor text.

If I use something like:

```
$("<a />", { text: $('<SPAN class="play" />') + "Track Name" })
```

then the span tags get escaped.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are several ways to do it, including (but not limited to):

```
// one big string
$('<a href="#"><span class="play"></span><span class="trackName">Track Name</span></a>')

// create <a> then append() the span
$('<a></a>').attr("href","#")
            .append('<span class="play"></span><span class="trackName">Track Name</span>');

// create <a> then set all of its contents with html()
$('<a></a>').attr("href","#")
            .html('<span class="play"></span><span class="trackName">Track Name</span>');

// append spans created earlier:
var spans = $('<span class="play"></span><span class="trackName">Track Name</span>');
var a = $('<a></a>').append(spans);
```

Note that `.html()` replaces any and all existing contents, while `.append()` adds to the end. So given that you have two span elements in your example you could create those independently and append them one at a time:

```
$('<a href="#"></a>').append('<span class="play"></span>')
                     .append('<span class="trackName">Track Name</span>');
```

Comment: Your last example is the one I went with.

Answer (score 7):

```
var link = $("<a>");
    link.attr("href","http://www.google.com");
    link.attr("title","Google.com");
    link.text("Google");
    link.addClass("link");
```

Answer (score 6):

Drop the internal jQuery constructor:

```
$("<a />", { text: '<SPAN class="play" /> Track Name' });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2dcN/).

or, if you want the code as HTML in the link:

```
$("<a />", { html: '<SPAN class="play" /> Track Name' });
```

Comment: the weirdest thing is that the cursor is no longer a pointer, so you'll need to add a style like on http://jsfiddle.net/f2dcN/41/, or have CSS to force the cursor into a pointer when hovering the anchor element

Answer (score 1):

This is what I eventually went with:

```
$('<a>', { className: 'trackName', href: contentPath + 'tracks/' + t.fileName } )
     .append('<span class="play" />')
     .append('<span class="trackName"></span>')
          .append(t.trackName)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//overwrites the innerHTML of all anchors *selector must be changed to more specific
$('a').html('<span class="play"></span><span class="trackName">Track Name</span>');

//wraps existing text and prepends the new span
$('a').wrapInner('<span class="trackName">')
    .prepend('<span class="play"></span>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gaboesquivel/f2dcN/3/