# How to create anchor tag

Tags: jquery

```
$(".unfriend").click(function () {
    $(".friends_slected").text("Add Friend");
    return false;
});
```

In this `.text("Add Friend");` Add Friend text is added from this.... but how can we make this Add Friend  an anchor tag not a simple text by using jQuery?

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus in that case he needs .html() instead of .text()

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304342/use-jquery-to-build-an-anchor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```
$('.friends_slected').wrap('<a href="#" />');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".unfriend").click(function () {
    $(".friends_slected").html("<a href='someurl'>Add Friend</a>");
    return false;
});
```

The .html method will let you add arbitrary html to your element

Comment: Simple and elegant way.

Comment: any way to remove this anchor tag's background when the previous anchor tag is replaced by this one???

Answer (score 1):

The html function takes an html string as input. So you just need to do:-

```
$(".friends_slected").html("<a href='anchor_url'>Add Friend</a>");
```

Hope that helps.