# Inserting href class to JS file (using createLink) Any ideas?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file that is pulling in data - all well and good.

However - I'd like to add a href class to the data that is outputted via AJAX.

```
        var craeteLink = function(cellValue, text) {
        return jQuery('<a/>', {                                 
        href: cellValue,
        text: text,
        target: "_blank",
        rel: "nofollow"
        })[0].outerHTML;
```

The above is the snippet of code that I believe makes the JS do its' magic with creating links but does anyone know the code to get the class to work? I tried class: but that didnt work....

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to just add a class to the anchor element?

Comment: Try `className` instead.

Comment: @Arun - I'd like to add a class to links that are generated so: href="" class=""

Comment: @Musa - nice idea...didnt work thou.....thanks thou....any other ideas?

Comment: you must use `"class":`, not `class:` in object literals to avoid the reserved name

Comment: Did you put comma after `rel: "nofollow"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative solution is

```
return jQuery('<a></a>', {                                 
    href: cellValue,
    text: text,
    target: "_blank",
    rel: "nofollow"
}).addClass('yourclassnamehere').[0].outerHTML;
```

Maybe this will help: [Use JQuery to build an anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304342/use-jquery-to-build-an-anchor)

---

Actually I tried putting class and it works for me:
http://jsbin.com/nunome

```
return jQuery('<a></a>', {                                 
    href: cellValue,
    text: text,
    target: "_blank",
    rel: "nofollow",
    class: "testclass",
})[0].outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class property to the element definition

```
var craeteLink = function (cellValue, text) {
    return jQuery('<a/>', {
        href: cellValue,
        text: text,
        target: "_blank",
        rel: "nofollow",
        'class': 'myclass'
    })[0].outerHTML;
}
```

---

If you want to pass the class as an argument

```
var craeteLink = function (cellValue, text ,clazz) {
    return jQuery('<a/>', {
        href: cellValue,
        text: text,
        target: "_blank",
        rel: "nofollow",
        'class': clazz
    })[0].outerHTML;
}
```